# Ubuntu 20.04.03 pausing for 2 minutes during boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

Running as a VM under Parallels on MacOS.  Used to boot fine - circa 10secs - now it's taking over 2 minutes and it's all in kernel (systems-analyze time):

```
Startup finished in 2min 2.911s (kernel) + 5.163s (userspace) = 2min 8.075s 
graphical.target reached after 5.138s in userspace
```

This can be seen in dmesg, a portion copied below:

```
...[snip]...
[    2.673238] fb0: switching to prldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    2.673270] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.11.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    2.673658] scsi host4: ahci
[    2.674010] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.6
[    2.674971] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    2.676406] scsi host5: ahci
[    2.679839] scsi host6: ahci
[    2.680667] input: Parallels Virtual Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:203A:FFFC.0001/input/input5
[    2.680864] hid-generic 0003:203A:FFFC.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Parallels Virtual Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[    2.683355] input: Parallels Virtual Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:203A:FFFC.0002/input/input6
[    2.683414] hid-generic 0003:203A:FFFC.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Parallels Virtual Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
[    2.683596] scsi host7: ahci
[    2.683829] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200100 irq 26
[    2.683834] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200180 irq 26
[    2.683836] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200200 irq 26
[    2.683839] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200280 irq 26
[    2.683860] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200300 irq 26
[    2.683864] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0200000 port 0xf0200380 irq 26
[    2.685452] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.686996] hub 4-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
[    2.688647] fbcon: prldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.689689] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[    2.690984] prl_vid 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: prldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.693005] virtio_net virtio0 enp0s5: renamed from eth0
[    2.709721] [drm] Initialized prl_vid 1.7.0 20210909 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    3.002031] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    3.002473] ata3.00: ATA-8: Ubuntu Linux-0 SSD, F.NB0GRW, max UDMA/100
[    3.002509] ata3.00: 1073741824 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[    3.002963] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    3.003413] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Ubuntu Linux-0 S 0GRW PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.003754] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    3.004067] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 1073741824 512-byte logical blocks: (550 GB/512 GiB)
[    3.004093] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.004954] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    3.005716] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.005762] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.027611]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    3.050540] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.318699] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    3.320847] ata4.00: ATAPI: Virtual DVD-ROM [1], FWR1, max UDMA/25
[    3.322856] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/25
[    3.325443] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM                     Virtual DVD-ROM  R103 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.383265] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 44x/44x cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    3.384340] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    3.446214] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    3.446545] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    3.563878] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
[    3.764290] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.082980] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.397906] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.718538] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[  122.808488] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[  122.927189] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[  122.947246] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.11 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[  122.948345] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm.
[  122.948681] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[  122.967752] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ubuntu-vm>.
[  123.102544] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prltoolsd.service:13: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/prltoolsd.pid → /run/prltoolsd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[  123.143913] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[  123.149406] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[  123.150410] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
...[snip]...
```

I can't tell if the delay is caused by mounting sda5 (it does say 'mounted...' which implies it has finished) or something else, e.g. an issue with ata8.  I don't know enough about Linux to be confident in this statement but I'm wondering if that many drives is related to (A) my Mac hard disk; (B) my connected SSD with the Linux VM on it; (c) mapped folders from the Mac.

I've tried booting without the quiet and splash options in grub but all I see is the long pause as shown above.  This is all before Journalctl and syslog get a look in so I can't find anything in there.

system-analyze blame or critical-chain show nothing useful.

I've tried booting with grub set to do no fsck but didn't help.  I've compared UUIDs:

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="0363354f-f8fb-46b5-a6f3-2cdefd508240" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="77746e54-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="D46A-1225" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="77746e54-01"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0363354f-f8fb-46b5-a6f3-2cdefd508240 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=D46A-1225  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

fdisk -l shows:

```
...[snip]...
Disk /dev/sda: 512 GiB, 549755813888 bytes, 1073741824 sectors
Disk model: Ubuntu Linux-0 S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x77746e54

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    1050623    1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 1073739775 1072687106 511.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 1073739775 1072687104 511.5G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

...[snip]...
```

I don't think that partition alignment is the issue, but could be wrong I suppose, because I haven't done anything with the disk image since creating it and, as I say, the problem only started recently.  The only things recently installed are Ubuntu-base fixes through Software-Updater but I can't pinpoint it to a specific time or event.

I'm stuck on how to troubleshoot this further, does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Disk mappings

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 13 16:24 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 13 16:24 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 13 16:24 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 13 16:24 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 13 16:24 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-2 -> ../../sr0
```

Also:

```
grep '[0-9]' /sys/class/scsi_host/host{0..9}/unique_id

/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/unique_id:1
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/unique_id:2
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/unique_id:3
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/unique_id:4
/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/unique_id:5
/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/unique_id:6
/sys/class/scsi_host/host6/unique_id:7
/sys/class/scsi_host/host7/unique_id:8
```

```
ls -lisah /sys/block
total 0
 3899 0 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 13 16:22 .
    1 0 dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Sep 13 16:22 ..
17686 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop0
17831 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop1 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop1
29992 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:39 loop10 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop10
17976 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop2 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop2
18121 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop3 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop3
18266 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop4 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop4
18411 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop5 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop5
18556 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop6 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop6
18701 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop7 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop7
26265 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop8 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop8
26417 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:24 loop9 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop9
25047 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:22 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda
25348 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:34 sr0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sr0
```

So I have host4-6 defined but nothing for those hosts, just hosts 2 and 3 (which seem ok in the boot messages.)

Comment: Between 3.764290 and 4.718538 four of your SATA Links dropped ou.! All your disks connected via the Serial ATA vanished. 118 seconds later, at 122.808408, the SATA links silently recovered and the boot continued. I suspect power or a problem with MacOS.

Comment: How can you tell they recovered at that time - because the delay ended?  I think those disks are likely to be mapped MacOS folders/drives.  I added some mapping information in my original post

Comment: I think this may be a bit of a red-herring.  The Parallels VM configuration gives me a choice of location for the VM hard disk and in that set of choices are SATA 0:1 to SATA 0:6.  Currently, location SATA 0:1 is selected.  That would imply that  if the boot drive takes one SATA slot, the virtual CD-ROM takes another SATA slot, that would leave 4 unused - in the logs, this seems to map to ATA3, ATA4 and ATA5-8 respectively.  My Mac has 0 physical SATA connections.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  The Parallels VM is configured with a disconnected CD-ROM drive - the options are disconnected or select an ISO image.  When the kernel boots it is being presented with an empty CD-ROM and it is trying to find a disk and then timing out.  If I configure the VM to use an ISO it boots without any delay.  This has started with kernel 5.11.0-34-generic but I don't know if it is a kernel issue or a Parallels issue.  Booting into an older version of the kernel seems to 'cure the problem'.

NOTE: this ALSO causes the problem with runaway systemd-udevd change events related to the cd-rom which causes systemd-udevd to ramp to 100% cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your findings, removing the CD/DVD drive completely in the Hardware Configuration settings seems to also fix the problem and obviate the need for keeping an ISO image permanently connected.